# Probe a single class in VisualVM

Tags: java, visualvm

Is it possible to probe a single class in visualVM? for example, I want to see how much time a method took to execute in a particular class.

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it is possible. If you are just interested in profiling one class, you can set profiling roots to just this class. See [Profiling With VisualVM, Part 1](https://web.archive.org/web/20111228184927/http://blogs.oracle.com/nbprofiler/entry/profiling_with_visualvm_part_1) and [Profiling With VisualVM, Part 2](https://web.archive.org/web/20111228050617/http://blogs.oracle.com/nbprofiler/entry/profiling_with_visualvm_part_2) to get more information about profiling and how to set profiling roots and instrumentation filter.